# Retrieve the Dockerfile configuration from the Kubernetes and also change container Java parameter?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, pods

I have a Java Spring Boot application running in a container within a Kubernetes pod. I'm wondering if there's a way to:

Retrieve the Dockerfile configuration from the Kubernetes cluster namespace without pulling it from the repository.

Suppose my Java application runs with JAVA_OPTS=X. I would like Kubernetes to somehow add to the JAVA_OPTS so that it becomes JAVA_OPTS=X,Y,Z, and then restart the pod. Additionally, I want the new configuration to be saved inside the container without modifying the original Dockerfile.

Comment: The question is not really related to programming. --- Kubernetes has no "insight" into the image, it just executes it. If we want to do what you described, we need to either fully override variable `JAVA_OPTS` (and hope this variable is not (re-)set in some entrypoint script) or add the functionality to the image (e.g. through a custom entrypoint script).